# What is onSubmitCheck for?

Tags: javascript, forms, inputbox

I'm working on a form which has this code in the submit button :

```
<input type="submit" onclick="return onSubmitCheck(document.forms['name'])">
```

When I delete this part `onclick="return onSubmitCheck(document.forms['name'])"` it works as normal as before so I don't have any idea what is that for.
Is it for security of form or something else?

Is it ok to remove it?

Comment: Please post the entire <form> because miss information

Comment: it's probably a function in your code for form validation. the form will work but you won't check if the form is valid

Comment: It's fine to remove it since the form can be posted without the validation running anyway.

Comment: @Inptbx—instead of posting code in a comment, edit your question to include it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the look of it, it is a JavaScript function which is suppose to run when you click on the submit button. You need to look at your JavaScript files and find the function and see what it does.
Whether it is safe to remove or not, depends on what it does.